# font-feature-settings features activated using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, webfonts

How do I activate and deactivate features within font-feature-settings using Javascript?

For example, if we have text that uses:

```
font-feature-settings: "ss01", "liga";
```

How can we add "ss02" to that list? 
Or remove "ss01" while keeping "liga"?

There are 12 different stylistic sets in the font plus another half-dozen basic features, so doing this with css classes (classList) gets out of hand rather quickly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

I made a variable that was the base font-feature-settings (including liga and kern because you should always turn on ligatures and kerning).

Then looked at the checkboxes to see what was turned on. Feature code was added to the variable.

When it was time to implement, existing fontFeatureSettings were removed, then we got any existing style attributes and added the new font-feature-settings.
Set the attribute and it's done.

```
function changeSS()     { 
    var function_on = "font-feature-settings: 'liga' 1, 'kern' 1,"

        if (document.getElementById("ss01").checked) { function_on += "'ss01' 1," };
        if (document.getElementById("ss02").checked) { function_on += "'ss02' 1," };
        if (document.getElementById("ss03").checked) { function_on += "'ss03' 1," };
        if (document.getElementById("ss04").checked) { function_on += "'ss04' 1," };

        function_on = function_on.slice(0,-1)+";"

        var txt = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
        for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
            txt[i].style.fontFeatureSettings = null; // nuke existing features
            var s = txt[i].style.cssText // get existing styles, then add font-feature-settings
            s += " " + function_on
            txt[i].setAttribute("style", s);
        }
```